# To Join consecutive rows

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have a table with 4 columns. The SQL fiddle for the same is as below:

```
CREATE TABLE Temp
(
ID INT IDENTITY(1,1),
BeginDateID INT,
EndDateID INT,
Duration INT
)

INSERT INTO Temp
VALUES(0, 2, 3),
(8, 10, 3),
(16, 17, 2),
(20, 20, 1)

SELECT * FROM Temp
```

This is what the actual data look like:

```
ID    BeginDateID    EndDateID    Duration
1      0                  2            3
2      8                  10           3
3      16                 17           2
4      20                 20           1
```

Now I will pass the ID values between EndDateID of 1st row and BeginDateID of 2nd row and so on into another proc and it will return boolean value. E.g. I will pass 41893, 41894, 41895....41897, 41901, 41902....41905, 41908, 41909 one by one. On passing these values i will get either 0 or 1. If I get all 0's for a slot, i.e. if I get 0 when I pass 41908 and 41909, the next row should be clubbed and final data should look like below:

```
ID    BeginDateID    EndDateID    Duration
1      0               2            3
2      8               10           3
3      16              20           3
```

Please let me know if any further clarification is needed.

Comment: What do you mean by - "Now I will pass the ID values between EndDateID of 1st row and BeginDateID of 2nd row and so on"

Comment: added details in the question

Comment: That's what not clear - please elaborate! your requirement is not clear and you have also not shown what you have tried to get the final data...

Comment: It is not clear what are you trying to do. Edit your question again.

Comment: your passing values 41893, 41894, 41895.... don't match with your table values... mention clearly what these values are ?